# How to implement relationships with inherits at the parent table to the children tables

Tags: database, postgresql, inheritance, relationship, data-modeling

I'm trying to implement a database that has inheritance between some tables, there is three tables involved in the question problem: Customers, Users and Addresses (actually there is more tables involved, but with the same problem, so..).

The **Customers** table inherits from **Users** table, and the **Users** table has a relationship with the **Addresses** table (1 to many, respectively).

So My problem is that I want that table 'Customers' to has the same relationship that 'Users' has with 'Addresses', cause Customers is inherits from it. I also try to insert data to 'Addresses' with an ID from 'Customers', but this give an `foreign key constraint violation, the value doesn't exists in table "myDb.users"` error

this is a image of my modeling:

[image: inherits model]

(**Note**: I'm actually using PostgreSQL, I'm just using the ADO.NET to modeling, and I know a way to get around this, but if has no way by inheritance I will change the entire DB to full relational-database.)

Comment: Do you require that foreign key constraint to point directly to Customers or is it acceptable to use built-in [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html) to handle that relation via parent (Users)?

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński it will not work smoothly unfortunately. If you have a record with id=1 in Customers, but no (direct) record with id=1 in Users, adding an address referencing user=1 into Addresses will violate the foreign key constraint.

Comment: @Dmitry You are right, just tested. I guess I'll leave it here in case someone else gets the same idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're using PostgreSQL table inheritance which, unfortunately, doesn't work quite as we would expect. In particular, although records from child tables appear in selects from parent table, they are not physically recorded there, and thus their ids can't be used in foreign keys referencing parent tables.

You may consider implementing inheritance using classic approach:

```
CREATE TABLE Users(id INT PRIMARY KEY, user_property INT);
CREATE TABLE Customers(id INT PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Users, customer_property INT);
CREATE TABLE Addresses(user_id INT REFERENCES Users, address TEXT);
```

This way you physically store properties of Customer in two tables, and you are sure that for every Customer there is a record in Users table which can be referenced from other tables.

```
-- inserting customer with id=1, user_property=10, customer_property=20
INSERT INTO Users(id, user_property) VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT INTO Customers(id, customer_property) VALUES (1, 20);
-- Inserting address
INSERT INTO Addresses(user_id, address) VALUES (1, 'Wall Street');
```

The drawback is that you need to join Users and Customers if you want to get all properties of a single customer from both tables:

```
-- All customer properties
SELECT * FROM Customers JOIN Users USING(id) WHERE Customers.id=1;
-- Customer and address
SELECT * FROM Customers JOIN Users USING(id) JOIN Addresses ON Users.id=Addresses.user_id WHERE Customers.id=1;
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but in other-side is sad that postgre doesn't have implemented this feature

Comment: on the positive side, it works with any relational DBMS.